# Spring cannot serve end point

Tags: spring

I have a simple Spring back-end. It has a folder that contains controllers.

```
package com.movieseat.controllers;

// Java imports
import java.util.List;

// Spring imports
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

// Project imports
import com.movieseat.models.Movie;
import com.movieseat.services.MovieService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/movies")
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/allMovies", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Movie> getAllMovies() {

        return movieService.getAllmovies();
    }     
}
```

In my Angular service I have a getAll() method:

```
public getAll<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.http.get<T[]>('/api/movies/allMovies');
}
```

When I run the application I get a:

> GET http://localhost:8090/api/movies/allMovies 404 ()

I have the server running on port 8090.

The following structure is used:

- com

  - movieseat

    - Application.java
    - controllers

      - MovieController.java
    - models

      - MovieModel.java
    - repositories

      - MovieRepository.java
    - services

      - impl

        - MovieServiceImpl.java
      - MovieService.java

Comment: if you didn't config the server port, the default should be 8080, so you need ti visit with GET http://locahost:8080/......

Comment: I have the server running on port 8090.

Comment: did you deploy war file on your tomcat or run it directly from ide?

Comment: please share your packages structure

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I've updated the question. I run the application from my backend folder using `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 0):

See if your controller class is picked up by spring scanning and performs mapping correctly. For example - If you are using Spring Boot, put a @SpringBootApplication on your main class that runs the app. The best way to know if your endpoint is scanned is to look for it when spring launches (in the log). You should look for something like

```
2017-09-17 14:45:49.522  INFO 2873 --- [main] RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/allMovies],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String  com.movieseat.controllers.MovieController.getAllMovies...
```

Comment: Hm I do have `@ComponentScan({"com.movieseat.repositories"})` in my Application.java because I got a message about missing bean files. Does this mean I exclude everything else, ie the controllers?

Comment: You need to make sure that you are scanning ALL components of your application. That being said, you should do a `@ComponentScan({"com.movieseat.*})` on your main configuration class (or main class).
Can you find your controller endpoint mapping in the logs upon application startup?

Comment: If I run it with a wildcard I get the message `Field movieRepository in com.movieseat.services.impl.MovieServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.movieseat.repositories.MovieRepository' that could not be found.`. So either it messes up the call for the repository or it calls the MovieServiceImpl which is giving back the error.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Are you using spring JPA repositories? If so, you should use `@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.movieseat.repositories.MovieRepository"})` annotation on your configuration class